# pandas extract function with regex behaves different then "normal" regex extraction?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I try to extract 1-n lines splittet by newline which are between a "start" (SOMEWORD in the example) and a "stop" word (SOME STOP WORD in the example) from a pandas dataframe through the str.extract method but it fails and the result is just NaN.
Examples provided below.

I have tried to build the regex with the help of regex101.com and there its working and even when i copy the auto generated example code from regex101.com in my jupyter notebook its extracting the lines as i would expect it.

Example code with pandas str.extract function:

```py
testInput = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['\nSOMEWORD\n---------- \nFirstline with some text\nSecondline with some text\nThirdline 
with some text\nSOME STOP WORD\n-------------------\n']})
pattern = r'(?<=\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n)(\w.+?(?=\nSOME STOP WORD))'
test = testInput.iloc[0].str.extract(pattern)
test
```

which outputs:

```py
text    NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Example code with regex101.com (i only include link so that the post does not get to long. At the site you can also copy the auto generated code which is working and does only extract the lines between the start and stop word): https://regex101.com/r/JM6Sgc/1

Therefore my 2 questions:

- why is my regex not working with the pandas str extract function
- why do i **dont** need to escape \n in the pandas extract function but on the regex101 site aswell as in "plain" regex code? Example pattern:

  - Successfully extract first line:

    - pattern = r'(?<=\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n)(\w.+)'
  - Fail to extract firstline and output NaN:

    - pattern = r'(?<=\\nSOMEWORD\\n----------\\n)(\w.+)'

Comment: There exist multiple regex implementations.  Seems like one application uses variant a, the other, variant b.

Comment: Could be possible ... do you have an idea how to fix my regex so thats working with pandas extract method?

Comment: You are mistaken about what string you have. You need to use `r'(?s)(?<=\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n)(\w.+?(?=\nSOME STOP WORD))'`. And this is a correct test: https://regex101.com/r/JM6Sgc/2. But you may also use `r'(?s)\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n(\w.+?)\nSOME STOP WORD'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JM6Sgc/3)), it is simpler.

Comment: the (?s) does the trick - thank you! Now i need just to catch up and read what the (?s) does and why i need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may discard lookarounds and make sure you match newlines and redefine the `.` behavior by using the `re.DOTALL` modifier (that you may set as an inline modifier, `(?s)`):

```
r'(?s)\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n(\w.+?)\nSOME STOP WORD'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JM6Sgc/3)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - an inline `re.DOTALL` modifier that makes `.` match any char including a newline char
- `\nSOMEWORD\n----------\n` - a literal substring where `\n` matches a literal LF char
- `(\w.+?)` - Group 1 (this value will be returned by `str.extract`): a word char followed with 1+ chars, as few as possible
- `\nSOME STOP WORD` - an LF and a `SOME STOP WORD` substring